# How to display images in a jsp file in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles2

I am very new to spring. I am using spring 3.29 version, tomcat 7. I need to display an image in .jsp file. I searched a lot. There are plenty of post about this problem. But still i am unable to solve this problem. Please help.

The following is my application structure

[image: The following is my application structure]

The following is my spring-servlet.xml file code

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.wipro.controller" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I have a page footer.jsp. I need to add an image in this file
The following is code

```
<!-- Here I need to add an image -->
<hr/>  
<p>Copyright  2010-2014 javatpoint.com.</p>
```

Comment: Which type of image you want to show? static or user based after login?

Comment: static image. That i have placed in images folder. Thanks for your time. Please help.

Comment: move your images folder to WebContent not to WEB-INF, and then you could add it in the HTML way with <img src="images/yourImage.yourExtension">

Comment: @Vincent: tried but not working.

Comment: what are the errors when you tried it ?

Comment: No Errors. Just image is not coming. Alternate text is coming in image tag of html

Comment: can you show the image path you are using after moving images folder into WebContent folder?

Comment: @ZaheerKhorajiya: The path is WebContent/images/wipLogo.png

Comment: You are doing wrong way , just use <img src="images/wipLogo.png" >

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the image in my page. @Pankaj Saboo comments helped a lot. Thanks for all of you.

I have added the below code in spring-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="WEB-INF/resources/images/" />
```

And in footer.jsp I have added the below code

```
<img src="<c:url value="/images/wipLogo.png" />"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add following line in your spring-servlet.xml

```
<resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
```

and on jsp

```
<link rel="icon"
href="http://<hostname>/projectname/images/imageName"/>
```

Comment: Once I add the line <resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" /> . I am getting some error. Invalid content ...

Comment: where you placed this line

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="com.wipro.controller" />

Comment: place this line before your component scan

Comment: for mor refer this link http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Comment: also use <mvc:resources>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90874/discussion-between-pankaj-saboo-and-abdul).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following resources declaration to your Spring configuration:

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /images/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/images directory -->
<resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
```

Alternatively, and more common, is to have a resources folder which contains all your resources (images, css, js, etc...), broken out by sub-directories.

Your configuration would then look like:

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

And your resources would be referenced as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/screen.css" />" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" />"></script>
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/left_arrow.png" />"
```